# Convert rows to columns in SQL in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, olap

I have data which looks like this:

| Name | Date | Bal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-01-01 | 10 |
| John | 2022-01-02 | 4 |
| John | 2022-01-03 | 7 |
| David | 2022-01-01 | 13 |
| David | 2022-01-02 | 15 |
| David | 2022-01-03 | 20 |

I want the `Bal` column populated under `date` column, like:

| Name | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | 4 | 7 |
| David | 13 | 15 | 20 |

What I tried is

```
SELECT 
NAME,
CASE WHEN DATE= '2022-01-01' THEN EOD_BALANCE ELSE NULL END "01-Jan-22",
CASE WHEN DATE= '2022-01-02' THEN EOD_BALANCE ELSE NULL END "02-Jan-22"
FROM TABL1
```

but I am not getting the required results. Below are the results from query in first answer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a pivot query here, which means you should aggregate by name and then take the max of the `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT 
    NAME,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE = '2022-01-01' THEN EOD_BALANCE END) AS "01-Jan-22",
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE = '2022-01-02' THEN EOD_BALANCE END) AS "02-Jan-22",
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE = '2022-01-03' THEN EOD_BALANCE END) AS "03-Jan-22" 
FROM TABL1
GROUP BY NAME;
```